Product of two exact represented doubles. Is exact?
Let's say that we have two double in Java:
double a, b; // a and b are any decimals that have exact representation in IEEE-754
Is it guaranteed that a * b and a / b returns exact result and has exact representation in double if it does not exceed +/- INF?

no, consider use cases like two very big numbers, or one very big another very small

My hunch is that it's obviously not, because if you use all available significant figures in both numbers, you will not have enough significant figures to exactly represent the result.

Double.MAX_VALUE * Double.MAX_VALUE will be INF

a=3, b=10, a / b is not going to be exact (because).

example from this question:  1.0 / 20.0

Any floating point number corresponds to a decimal number which has an exact representation. So you're essentially asking "is FP division or multiplication (with a finite result) always exact".

@Sneftel Not at all. You may want t look up IEEE-754; the way double/float represent floating point numbers is quite different from how humans tend to do it.

Any binary floating-point number (with finite precision) can be exactly represented as a human-readable decimal. Thus, any float or double value can be converted to BigDecimal without loss of precision.

I stressed binary above because this property doesn't hold for other bases in general. For example, imagine a computer, perhaps made by an alien civilization on another planet, that used ternary bits instead of binary ones. 0, 1 and 2, instead of just 0 and 1. Then 1/3 would be precisely representable in their flavour of double but not precisely representable as a decimal.

@rzwitserloot No, this is definitely true. I think you think I was saying the reverse -- that every decimal number has an exact floating point representation. That's not what I said. Every floating point number can be represented as a*2^b, with a and b integers; all integer powers of 2 have an exact decimal representation; that property is closed under multiplication; so all floating point numbers have exact decimal representation.

No.  Imagine two numbers a and b that meet the requirement. That means that a op b is exact.  Now continue the process as below.
double a = 1.5; // exact
double b = 1.5; // exact

BigDecimal c = new BigDecimal("1.5");
BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal("1.5");

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    if (!new BigDecimal(a).equals(c)) {
      System.out.printf("Diff at loop %d: %.50f vs %.50f\n",
        i, c, new BigDecimal(a));
      break;
    }
    a *= b; // a is presumed to be exact each time based on assumption
    c = c.multiply(d);
}

prints
Diff at loop 33: 970739,73736647568875923752784729003906250000000000000000 vs
                 970739,73736647563055157661437988281250000000000000000000


The conclusion is correct but the proof is not. System.out.println applies a light amount of rounding; the fact that sysout fails to print a number ending in 5 does not prove that rounding has occurred. (To be clear, it has occurred; it's simply that your code snippet does not prove that it has occurred).

Specifically, the rules are that sysout / Double.toString) prints as many digits as are needed to uniquely distinguish it from any other double. I believe that System.out.printf("%.99f\n", new BigDecimal(a)); does the job you want it to here.

In fact, I can confirm! The number ends in 5 for every cycle of this loop, the only reason it does not in the sysout is due to the rounding rules of sysout!

That thought had occurred to me.  Perhaps I should have said intuitively due to lack of space in the significand or show the actual bits.  I will work on it.

I have thoroughly edited your answer's snippet; it seemed like a better solution than posting a separate answer (because the credits go to you for coming up with the notion that 1.5 * 1.5 repeatedly applied is inevitably going to prove it, a keen insight), and the fixed snippet didn't fit in a comment. If you don't like it by all means revert.

Hmm, I was all 'wow this is great' but in retrospect.. the result of 1/3 isn't exact, obviously isn't exact, and yet 1 and 3 are both exact, that's.. perhaps a much simpler way to prove it.

Here is a simple counterexample.  Consider:
a = 23227615.65625;
b = 959782.0751953125;

Both of these numbers are exactly representable in IEEE-754 double-precision floating point, having 30 bits of precision each (comfortably less than 53).
Their product is exactly 22293449156394.755401611328125, but this number is not representable, having 60 bits.  The closest result you can get in IEEE-754 is 22293449156394.75390625, with 53 bits.
(I was going to show this result with some actual Java code, but as @rzwitserloot points out in a comment, "System.out.println applies a light amount of rounding", so I kept getting 22293449156394.754.)
In general, the product of two numbers with M and N bits of precision will have M+N bits of precision.  And it's worse for division.  So, no, products and quotients are usually not exact.
